# LDAP Filter Question

Tags: ldap

This is the filter I am using:

```
(&(ObjectClass=user)(employeeID=*)(mail=*))
```

And I get back what I need. However, there are way too many results return and so I want to only get those users whose sn starts with an 'a'.

So, I changed my filter to:

```
(&(ObjectClass=user)(employeeID=*)(mail=*)(sn=a*))
```

But there is no change in the results from the orignal filter.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tested on my local server, first filter returned 100002 entries, second returned 3871 entries. 1. Are you sure you changed the filter? 2. you could use the simple paged result control to get back the entries in groups of a number you specify. Note also that `employeeId=*` and `mail=*` are presence filters, they match entries that have the attribute with a value.

Comment: On wich directory are you working ?
I ask the question, because your problem may be explained by the matching rules in use for the attribute 'sn'.

Comment: Terry, I reran my ldapsearch with sn=a* just to make sure and yes, there is no difference. Also, yes, I only want those users return who have a value specified for employeeId and mail.

Comment: JPBlanc, I am new to LDAP/AD and so, don't understand what you mean when you say 'which directory.' Can you explain? Thx. :)

Comment: He means which implementation of LDAP. Active Directory, NDS, OpenLDAP, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication of that is that the filter (sn=a*) doesn't actually work, which is hard to believe. You could try putting it first in the filter string, but I think it's much more likely that you aren't executing the code you think you're executing.

Comment: I up voted this answer because I agree that something is odd here, however, the placement of the filter components should not be counted on to change the results in any way whatsoever with the possible exception of performance: with the substring filter first vs. last, OpenLDAP shows worse performance,  OpenDS shows better performance, Sun DSEE 5.2 shows no measurable difference.